# Excel - generating data with specific criteria

Tags: excel, distribution

I want to do the following in Excel, without VBA/macros:

1. input a number, e.g. 10.97
2. output a distribution with the following criteria:

   - total numbers in distribution = 52
   - sum of 52 numbers = input of 10.96
   - numbers should be percentages, starting at 100% and declining each time

If this isn't clear, here is the reverse:
the sum of this set of numbers is 10.96.

```
100%
62%
45%
39%
37%
35%
33%
31%
31%
28%
27%
26%
25%
23%
22%
22%
22%
21%
20%
20%
19%
18%
18%
17%
16%
16%
14%
13%
13%
13%
13%
13%
14%
14%
14%
14%
14%
13%
13%
13%
13%
13%
13%
13%
13%
12%
12%
10%
9%
9%
9%
10%
```

Comment: Can the Solver do this? What have you tried? What has/hasn't worked?

Comment: I'm trying but struggling to do this in Solver, as I have never used it before. Could you perhaps provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the input value (e.g. 10.96) is in the cell B2.

In the beginning we will generate random number. We will put this equation to cell A5:

```
=RAND()
```

Then we will extend this formula down to the cell A55, so we have 51 randomly generated numbers. Now we will create a sequence of numbers from 1 to 51 at the C column. We will begin at the row 5. So we should have 1 at C5, 2 at C6 and so on.

We will put a sum of the generated numbers to the cell A2, so the A2 will have a formula:

```
=SUM(A5:A55)
```

Now we will sort these numbers by function. We will put this formula into D5 cell:

```
=LARGE($A$4:$A$55;C5)
```

Now we will put this formula into cell E5:

```
=D5/$A$2*($B$1-1)
```

We will extend both cell formula at column D5 and E5 down to row 55. Finally we will add 1 as a constant to cell E4. The result is at column E at range E4:E55.

Maybe there is a problem for you that there is a big gap between 100 % value and the biggest generated value. We can fix this by powering the randomly generated number. Fox example we can use this formula for the randomly generated numbers:

```
=POWER(RAND();2)
```

This is a sample result of this procedure:

```
100%
56%
51%
49%
46%
46%
46%
44%
44%
35%
34%
31%
31%
31%
31%
30%
29%
26%
26%
25%
22%
19%
18%
17%
17%
17%
16%
15%
14%
14%
13%
11%
11%
10%
9%
8%
7%
6%
6%
6%
6%
5%
5%
4%
3%
3%
2%
1%
1%
0%
0%
0%
```

You can check that the sum of the numbers is 1096%.

Here you can see sample sheet: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvP6NwTpIPzsmIYOuGOjuOZRFRc-3g

Comment: Thanks - this works well. Slightly annoying is that the random function refreshes each time, but I guess there is no way around this with simple formulas. This does the job though - thanks :)

Comment: One more question: what would I need to do for the final value to be 15%. Starting from 100% to 15%?

Comment: If you do not want to generate a new random set after leaving a cell, you can change Workbook calculation settings. Open the workbook. Then go to the Excel Options, and then click the Formulas category. Then select Manual in Calculating Options. You can use F9 key to recalculate the workbook.

Comment: I have updated the sample file. I have added some numerical value (like 0.2) to F2 cell and a this formula to range F5:F55.
`=E5*($F$2)+0,15`
Then I have added a formula
`=SUM(F5:F55)`
to cell F1. Then I used Solver with following settings:
- Set Objective: $F$1
- Value Of: 10.96
- By Changing Variable Cells: $F$2
- Contraint: $F$5:$F$55 <= 1

Comment: Please make sure that you have constant values in the A column before running a Solver.